# Creating a new LinkedList or Arraylist

Tags: java, list

What's the difference between this:

```
List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
```

and this?

```
LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface